# How to sort a String Array first by letters in the beginning and then by numbers afterwards

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I am attempting to sort a large String array. I want it to be ordered primarily by the words in the beginning, based on an order that I have. But I have more than 1 item with the same beginning word, so I want to be able to order the words with numbers that are after the initial word.

For example:

```
String[] unordered = {"Pencil 2", "Cat 3", "Pencil 1", "Cat 1", "Cat 2"}
```

I would want the result of sort to be:

```
String[] ordered = {"Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3", "Pencil 1", "Pencil 2"}
```

As it stands right now, I am sorting my list while ignoring the numbers afterwards. So I end up with something like this:

```
String somewhat ordered = {"Cat 3", "Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Pencil 2", "Pencil 1"}
```

My code right now looks like this:

```
String[] sortlist = {"Pencil 2", "Cat 3", "Pencil 1", "Cat 1", "Cat 2"}

String[] Bookorder = {"Cat", "Pencil", etc...}

List<String>[] results = new List[bookorder.length];
            LinkedList<String> remainders = new LinkedList<String>();

            for (String word : sortlist) {
                boolean found = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < bookorder.length; i++) {
                    if (word.startsWith(bookorder[i])) {
                        if (results[i] == null) results[i] = new LinkedList<String>();
                        results[i].add(word);
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found) {
                    remainders.add(word);
                }
            }

            finalsortedlist = new ArrayList<String>(sortlist.length);
            for (List<String> result : results) {
                if (result != null) {
                    finalsortedlist.addAll(result);
                }
            }

            finalsortedlist.addAll(remainders);

            String[] finalsortedarray = new String[finalsortedlist.size()];
            finalsortedarray = finalsortedlist.toArray(finalsortedarray);

            dblinesequivalent = Arrays.toString(finalsortedarray);
```

This works great, except for the fact that it doesn't sort the numbers. I can't figure out a way to do this without messing up the previous sorting of the words.

I would appreciate any help you would be willing to offer. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I do not wish to sort the items alphabetically, they are sorted based on another list the specifies the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void reorder() {
    String[] unordered = {"Pencil 2", "Cat 3", "Pencil 1", "Cat 1", "Cat 2"};
    Arrays.sort(unordered);
}
```

EDIT: Here's a version that works for all numbers

```
private static void reorder() {
    String[] unordered = { "Pencil 2", "Cat 11", "Pencil 1", "Cat 1", "Cat 2" };
    Arrays.sort(unordered);
    System.out.println("After Arrays.sort()");
    for (String s : unordered)
        System.out.println(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < unordered.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < unordered.length - 1; j++) {
            if (unordered[i].substring(0, unordered[i].indexOf(' '))
                    .equals(unordered[j].substring(0, unordered[j].indexOf(' ')))) {
                String numI = unordered[i].substring(unordered[i].indexOf(' ') + 1);
                String numJ = unordered[j].substring(unordered[j].indexOf(' ') + 1);
                if (Integer.parseInt(numI) > Integer.parseInt(numJ)) {
                    String tmp = unordered[i];
                    unordered[i] = unordered[j];
                    unordered[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After sorting");
    for (String s : unordered)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Note this only works if the numbers only go through 9.

Comment: Can you explain this to me? It looks like you are using the completely unordered list, if I use my partially ordered list will it still work? Will it keep the sorting of the words, and just change the items position relative to the other items containing the same words in the beginning?

Comment: I didn't see that first comment. They do go higher than that. Any other ideas?

Comment: I see that you completely changed the way you are going about this. I don't  think that this will keep the right order using the words in front. Is that not right?

Comment: Can you explain what is going on? When I sort with Arrays.sort() it messes up the order that I already attained using my sorting method. What I want to do is to sort what I have using the numbers.

Comment: @MJDude Remove all of your sorting code and use my code instead.

Comment: But I don't want to sort the files alphabetically, I sort them based on another list. I believe that your code is only sorting them alphabetically.